Why should we use lazy loading if browser caches the project's bundle files?
I understand that browser caching can store bundled files for faster retrieval, so once the user has visited the site, subsequent visits should load the cached files rather than downloading them again. However, in this scenario, why is lazy loading still recommended in Angular applications or any single-page applications (SPAs)? Is it necessary if the browser already caches the entire project’s bundle?
I implemented lazy loading in my Angular app and tested it with browser caching enabled. I used Chrome DevTools to monitor the caching behavior.
I expected caching to make lazy loading less necessary, since cached files should load faster, but I wasn’t sure if this would affect initial load time and performance the same way.

Lazy loading in SPA is recommended even if browser caching is in place. It offers advantages in terms of initial load time and resource efficiency:

Lazy loading reduces the size of the initial packet that needs to be downloaded when a user first visits your site.
Initial loading of a large package consumes a lot of memory and resources. Lazy loading loads modules only when they are needed, minimizing resource consumption.
Application updates cause cache collapse, then users have to download a new version of the entire package. Lazy loading splits the application into smaller chunks, so only the updated parts need to be downloaded.
If network connectivity is poor or unstable, downloading smaller amounts of data as needed can improve user experience and enable faster interactions.

